# slow running script. How can I increase its speed?

Tags: performance, awk, sed, zsh

How can I speed this up? it's taking about 5 minutes to make one file... 
it runs correctly, but I have a little more than 100000 files to make.

Is my implementation of awk or sed slowing it down? I could break it down into several smaller loops and run it on multiple processors but one script is much easier.

```
#!/bin/zsh
#1000 configs per file

alpha=( a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z )
m=1000 # number of configs per file
t=1 #file number
for (( i=1; i<=4; i++ )); do
  for (( j=i; j<=26; j++ )); do
    input="arc"${alpha[$i]}${alpha[$j]}
    n=1 #line number
    #length=`sed -n ${n}p $input| awk '{printf("%d",$1)}'`
    #(( length= $length + 1 ))
length=644

for ((k=1; k<=$m; k++ )); do
    echo "$hmbi" >> ~/Glycine_Tinker/configs/config$t.in
    echo "jobtype = energy" >> ~/Glycine_Tinker/configs/config$t.in
    echo "analyze_only = false" >> ~/Glycine_Tinker/configs/config$t.in
    echo "qm_path = qm_$t" >> ~/Glycine_Tinker/configs/config$t.in
    echo "mm_path = aiff_$t" >> ~/Glycine_Tinker/configs/config$t.in
    cat head.in >> ~/Glycine_Tinker/configs/config$t.in
    water=4
    echo $k
  for (( l=1; l<=$length; l++ )); do
    natom=`sed -n ${n}p $input| awk '{printf("%d",$1)}'`
    number=`sed -n ${n}p $input| awk '{printf("%d",$6)}'`
    if [[ $natom -gt 10 && $number -gt 0 ]]; then
     symbol=`sed -n ${n}p $input| awk '{printf("%s",$2)}'`
     x=`sed -n ${n}p $input| awk '{printf("%.10f",$3)}'`
     y=`sed -n ${n}p $input| awk '{printf("%.10f",$4)}'`
     z=`sed -n ${n}p $input| awk '{printf("%.10f",$5)}'`

     if [[ $water -eq 4 ]]; then
     echo "--" >> ~/Glycine_Tinker/configs/config$t.in
     echo "0 1 0.4638" >> ~/Glycine_Tinker/configs/config$t.in
     water=1
     fi


     echo "$symbol  $x  $y  $z" >> ~/Glycine_Tinker/configs/config$t.in
     (( water= $water + 1 ))
    fi
    (( n= $n + 1 ))

  done
  cat tail.in >> ~/Glycine_Tinker/configs/config$t.in
  (( t= $t + 1 ))
 done

 done

done
```

Comment: Every time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. The shell is an environment from which to call tools with a language to sequence those calls. The UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk. You need to discard that shell script and start over writing the whole thing in awk, anything else is once again the wrong approach and the awk script will run in the blink of an eye. If you'd like help then post some sample input and expected output.

Comment: You should not use old and deprecated back tics, use parentheses, example: `x=$(sed -n ${n}p $input| awk '{printf("%.10f",$3)}')`

Comment: @Jotne: The `\`…\`` (backtick) syntax isn't actually _deprecated_ (nothing in the [POSIX shell spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) mentions that), but _there are good reasons to use  `$(…)` instead_: quoting and backslash-escaping work as expected (no extra quoting needed); similarly, `$(…)` can easily be _nested_ without the need for additional quoting - see mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that is going to be killing you here is the sheer number of processes being created.  Especially when they are doing the exact same thing.

Consider doing the `sed -n ${n}p $input` once per loop iteration.

Also consider doing the equivalent of awk as a shell array assignment, then accessing the individual elements.

With these two things you should be able to get the 12 or so processes (and the shell invocation via back quotes) down to a single shell invocation and the backquote.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, Ed's advice is far preferable, but if you don't want to follow that, I had a couple of thoughts...

**Thought 1**

Rather than run `echo` 5 times and `cat head.in` onto the `Glycine file`, each of which causes the file to be opened, seeked (or sought maybe) to the end, and appended, you could do that in one go like this:

```
# Instead of 
hmbi=3
echo "$hmbi"            >> ~/Glycine_thing
echo "jobtype = energy" >> ~/Glycine_thing
echo "somethingelse"    >> ~/Glycine_thing
echo ...                >> ~/Glycine_thing          
echo ...                >> ~/Glycine_thing
cat  ...                >> ~/Glycine_thing

# Try this
{
  echo "$hmbi"
  echo "jobtype = energy"
  echo "somethingelse"
  echo
  echo
  cat head.in
} >> ~/Glycine_thing

# Or, better still, this
echo -e "$hmbi\njobtype = energy\nsomethingelse" >> Glycine_thing

# Or, use a here-document, as suggested by @mklement0
cat -<<EOF >>Glycine
$hmbi
jobtype = energy
next thing
EOF
```

**Thought 2**

Rather than invoke `sed` and `awk` 5 times to find 5 parameters, just let `awk` do what `sed` was doing, and also do all 5 things in one go:

```
read symbol x y z < <(awk '...{printf "%.10f %.10f %.10f" $2,$3,$4}' $input)
```

Comment: Good suggestions; you could also mention a here-document as an alternative to either grouping the `echo` commands or using a single string with escape sequences. You could avoid a subshell if you group the  `echo` commands with `{...}` instead.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for the suggestions. Hopefully I have edited them in how you intended - if not, please feel free to correct/improve me!